# gitlab installations with desired domain(http://gitlab.<name>.com)

Tags: version-control, dns, gitlab, admin

i am really fed up with git lab installations. i tried so many ways by referring some websites.but not succeeded.

1> when i install i can access via only my machine ip. but **"i need to install in such a way that i should access in my private network using http://gitlab.com"**.

2> i dont know how to configure DNS and also NGNIX, is DNS and NGINX relally required to configure gitlab in private network?

your suggestions and answers are really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You could add a line to your /etc/hosts.txt of the form `my.ip.add.ress gitlab.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your Gitlab instance after installation? This guide walks you through configuring all the options, and how to make the configuration take effect: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html

If you did and it still isn't working, can you update your question with your gitlab.rb file?